# PostgreSQL : dependencies on a schema

Tags: postgresql, schema, delete, dependencies

I need to delete a schema in my PostgreSQL database. I would like to make sure that the schema is not used in another schema (for instance : this schema is used for a view in another one). Is there a way to list all the dependencies in the rest of the database ?

I have tried `DROP SCHEMA mySchema ;` but the given list of dependencies is partial...

Many thanks for help !

Answer (score 1):

You can use pg_depend table to resolve that :

```
select objid::regclass 
from pg_depend 
where refobjid = (select oid
                  from pg_namespace 
                  where nspname='mySchema');
```

Comment: Thanks. I just tried with a schema known to be referenced in oustside views. The query result just returns a list of tables but I don't know from which schema they are from...

Comment: Ok, sorry, understood.

Answer (score 1):

here's a quick and ugly query that make the job :

```
with nsp_oid as (
  select oid from pg_namespace
    where nspname='mySchema'
), 
dep_oid as (
  select p.objid as oid
    from pg_depend p
    join nsp_oid n
      on refobjid = n.oid 
), 
rew_oid as(
  select p.objid as oid
    from pg_depend p
    join dep_oid d
      on p.refobjid = d.oid
    where p.classid::regclass::text = 'pg_rewrite'
)
select distinct refobjid::regclass
  from pg_depend p
  join  rew_oid r 
    on ( r.oid in ( p.refobjid, p.objid ))
  where deptype='n';
```

Comment: Ugly indeed ;-) ! A closing bracket is missing. But where do I put my schema name ? Thanks for that.

Comment: in nspname, in the first CTE ( nspname='mySchema' )

Comment: It's ugly since your formating leaves a lot to be desired.

Comment: I get this : `ERROR : more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression`.

Comment: Yeah, maybe subqueries needs to be join, actually

Comment: Still strange result... I get 135775 lines after a 30 sec. query treatment. And still a list of relations without possibility to know from which schema they are from...

Comment: relations without schemaname means that schema is in the `search_path` variable ; add `distinct` give unique results

Comment: HI ! The result is not what I really need. It lists both relations from inside the schema and outside the schema... I need to get the other shemas that use the schema I want to delete, to make sure that it is not going to impact other ones. Sorry, my query is a bit complicated.

Comment: I finally used `DROP TABLE ...` on each table, then passed a `DROP SCHEMA ...` that did not show any dependencies issues.